# How can i connect to my friend through internet with sockets?

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, network-programming

I've written the game on C with sockets which perfectly works on LAN, but how can i connect to my friend through internet? Our ip addr. are dynamic, but even so (i can recompile program with current values and give him it), what should i enter? hostname gives 127.0.0.1 or 192.168.*.*, both are correct and absolutely logical, can someone help me and say any method for connecting each other?
P.S. UNIX platform;

Comment: Are you behind a router / NAT ?

Comment: Yes, myPC -> router -> ISP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off the IP you're looking for is your public IP. To find it, simply google "what's my ip" from both locations, and that'll give you the two IPs. Second you'll need to configure your routers to perform port forwarding.

Comment: i've tried this but at that time i hadn't heard any about port forwarding, thanks for now, will keep trying and if that works - answer is yours)

Comment: And one more thing, UNIX system i mentioned about, it's virtual machine, can this be a problem even if i set up everything correctly?

Comment: You shouldn't have a problem, as long as the virtual system can connect to the internet, it should be connecting to your router :)